# How to prevent PYQT app from crashing when a part of a thread is stopped

Tags: pyqt, thread-safety

I have a PYQT6 application that gets inputs and launches Selenium tests. I have each test running in a thread so I can run multiple tests. I noticed if for some reason I close the webdriver manually (clicking the X on the browser) to end the selenium test the whole app crashes. This does not happen if the selenium test encounters an error and triggers an exeption and closes the browser.

I tried wrapping the selenium test in a try/except statement in the workerthread but that doenst seem to help.

End goal is to be able to launch a test and close out the browser without my main app crashing. I prefer not to put a button in the App saying destroy the thread.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Please provide a [mre].